# Collapse tree nodes at initial load question

Tags: javascript, html, tree

hopefully you can earn some good Karma by helping me today.

I have some code for a Wix Velo site that is kind working, but keeps opening all the tree elements when loaded.

Please can someone have a look and suggest how to start the tree nodes as collapsed?

It is for a special needs school and I am unpaid, so it is definitely for a good cause!

Cheers,

```
[https://codepen.io/jimbbobleeharry/pen/VwrEage][1]

<style>
  .plus,
  .minus {
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px !important;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  }
  
  .plus {
    background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/plus.png);
  }
  
  .minus {
    background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/minus.png);
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  }
  
  ul.inner_ul li:before {
    content: "├";
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    width: 8px;
    color: #41424e;
  }
  
  ul.inner_ul li:last-child:before {
    content: "└";
  }
  
  .inner_ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
  }
  
  .w-50 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .d-flex {
    display: flex;
    color: #a57164;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .selected-node {
    color: chocolate;
  }
</style>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="tree_main w-50">
    <ul id="bs_main" class="main_ul">
      <li id="bs_1">
        <span class="plus minus">&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c_bs_1">

        <span class="title">
                ADHD </span>
        <ul id="bs_l_1" class="sub_ul">
          <li id="bf_1">
            <span class="plus minus">&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c_bf_1">
            <span class="title">
                        Verbal</span>
            <ul id="bf_l_1" style="display: block;" class="inner_ul">
              <li id="io_1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_1">
                <span class="title">
                                Catch, Match and Redirect </span>
              </li>
              <li id="io_2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_2">
                <span class="title">
                                Entering shared space scripts </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="bf_2">
            <span class="plus minus">&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c_bf_2">
            <span class="title">
                        Non-Verbal</span>
            <ul id="bf_1_2" class="inner_ul">
              <li id="io_5">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_5">
                <span class="title">
                                Signing and hand signals </span>
              </li>
              <li id="io_6">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_6">
                <span class="title">
                                Voices off timer </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="bf_3">
            <span class="plus minus">&nbsp;</span>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c_bf_3">
            <span class="title">
                        Other</span>
            <ul id="bf_l_3" class="inner_ul">
              <li id="io_7">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_7">
                <span class="title">
                                Environmental barriers to aid focus </span>
              </li>
              <li id="io_8">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_8">
                <span class="title">
                                Are routines embedded? Could they be? </span>
              </li>
              <li id="io_9">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_9">
                <span class="title">
                                Lead Learner not key person (to avoid attachement compliciations) </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to handle that this way:

```
<style>
  .plus,
  .minus {
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 16px !important;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
  }
  
  .plus {
    background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/plus.png);
  }
  
  .minus {
    background-image: url(https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/minus.png);
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  }
  
  ul.inner_ul li:before {
    content: "├";
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    width: 8px;
    color: #41424e;
  }
  
  ul.inner_ul li:last-child:before {
    content: "└";
  }
  
  .inner_ul {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
  }
  
  .w-50 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  .d-flex {
    display: flex;
    color: #a57164;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .selected-node {
    color: chocolate;
  }
  .inner-content{
    display: inline;
  }
 .hide{
    
    display: none;
 }
</style>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="tree_main w-50">
    <ul id="bs_main" class="main_ul">
      <li id="bs_1">
        <span class="plus minus">&nbsp;</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c_bs_1">

        <span class="title">
                ADHD </span>
        <ul id="bs_l_1" class="sub_ul">
          <li id="bf_1">
            <span class="plus minus collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="inner-content">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_bf_1">
                <span class="title">
                            Verbal</span>
                <ul id="bf_l_1" style="display: block;" class="inner_ul">
                  <li id="io_1">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_1">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Catch, Match and Redirect </span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="io_2">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_2">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Entering shared space scripts </span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="bf_2">
            <span class="plus minus collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="inner-content">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_bf_2">
                <span class="title">
                            Non-Verbal</span>
                <ul id="bf_1_2" class="inner_ul">
                  <li id="io_5">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_5">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Signing and hand signals </span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="io_6">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_6">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Voices off timer </span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li id="bf_3">
            <span class="plus minus collapsible">&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="inner-content">
                <input type="checkbox" id="c_bf_3">
                <span class="title">
                            Other</span>
                <ul id="bf_l_3" class="inner_ul">
                  <li id="io_7">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_7">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Environmental barriers to aid focus </span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="io_8">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_8">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Are routines embedded? Could they be? </span>
                  </li>
                  <li id="io_9">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="c_io_9">
                    <span class="title">
                                    Lead Learner not key person (to avoid attachement compliciations) </span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>




 <script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var innerContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    innerContent.classList.toggle("hide");
  });
}
</script>
```

I changed some structure of HTML and add a bit of CSS to your code.

Also, you can change the minutes to plus. just play with the javascript events and make something better.

Comment: Thank you soo much for looking at this.

Comment: You are welcome, I was seeking good Karma :D. let me know If you have any questions.

Comment: I just tried to put the changes in, but it does not want to play nice and has  locked out the first branch for expanding as well as the Ticked Node elements. 

I will give it a couple days and admit defeat. Good Karma for you though sajjad!

Comment: Dont give up man. just let me know if you have any questions in the future about this or any topic. looking forward to helping you :).

Comment: I just wish there was a simple solution that didn't involve creating more lines of code haha.